# Django MPTT : how to implement recursetree inside a recursetree tag.

Tags: django, django-mptt, mptt

Its like inception here .

```
<ul class="root">
    {% recursetree nodes %}
              {% recursetree #i get values dependsing on node which is a mptt model %}
                   {{ node.name }}
              {% endrecursetree %} 
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

Now how do i implement such a scenario wit mptt ??? .. or is mptt a bad choice in this case ? which i am beginning to think it is .

Any help is really appreciated .

Thanks :)